# Share buttons with count in codeigniter application

Tags: codeigniter, share-button

I have developed an application in Codeigniter, I want to add share buttons with count(like as, facebook, twitter,google+ etc), in the application. Please help me how to add it.

Comment: Please can you post your codes what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is the HTML code: <span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span> For this I have used some JS code.

Comment: For the core PHP application its working fine, but, in case of codeigniter its not working properely

Comment: Can you please post your JS code too?

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.async=true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Comment: script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-1c405a7-8efe-7b0d-5e82-6658c2523eb3", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>